# monitor not recognized after update

Tags: monitor

I installed 20.04-2 and my monitor was recognized: Dell 1920x1080
I upgraded to get the latest software.
The monitor is no longer recognized (no monitor is) and I end up with 800x600

Comment: by 'upgraded' do you mean you went to 21.10?  If so, did you run `ubuntu-drivers` tool since then to install the latest driver for your graphics card?

Comment: I solved it by apt install of the correct driver. I do not know why it worked after a fresh install and then failed to recognize the monitor and its resolution after and apt update